# Search json data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, regex, select

I have json data stored in a MySQL database like this:

```
{"size":["S","M","L"],"in_stock":["1","1","1"],"articleid":["102802","102803","102804"]}
```

I'm trying to get only data in return that has *size:M* with the following SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id>0 AND sizescolors REGEXP '"size":"([^"])"M"([^"])"'
```

The only problem is, it return zero results. Is there something wrong with my regular expression?

Thank you in advance,
Dennis

Comment: Why are you storing a JSON object instead of several MySQL fields?

Comment: Hi, mysql REGEX based search is very slow and unindexable. If your table builds up you will have insane speed issues. Mysql is a relational database, so create tables to store your data and that will make your life alot easyer. Storing things like JSON in DB is for archiving, those field should never be used in search.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with php:

```
$Json = json_decode($Data['rowName']);

foreach($Json->size as $Size){
    $Sizes[$Size] = $Size;

       foreach($Json->in_stock as $InStock){
           $Stock[] = $InStock;
       }

}

if($Stock['0']==TRUE){
    echo $Sizes['S'] . " Is in stock (".$Stock['0']." left)<br/>";
}
else{
    echo $Sizes['S'] . " not in stock.<br/>";
}


if($Stock['1']==TRUE){
    echo $Sizes['M'] . " Is in stock (".$Stock['1']." left)<br/>";
}
else{
    echo $Sizes['M'] . " not in stock.<br/>";
}

if($Stock['2']==TRUE){
    echo $Sizes['L'] . " Is in stock (".$Stock['2']." left)";  
}
else{
    echo $Sizes['M'] . " not in stock.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        //fetch the json data from mysql and store in variable
        $str ='{"size":["S","M","L"],"in_stock":["1","1","1"],"articleid":["102802","102803","102804"]}';

        //decode json into associate array
        $data=json_decode($str,true);

        //variable to get position of size=M
//position is needed because may size=M may be at any location like size=M, L, S, XL, XLL, etc
        $i=0;
        foreach($data as $key=>$value)
        {
            if($data['size'][$i]=='M')//if size M got. then at that same location find data
            {
                $size=$data['size'][$i];
                $in_stock=$data['in_stock'][$i];
                $articleid=$data['articleid'][$i];
                echo $size." ".$in_stock." ".$articleid;
                break;//to stop further search
            }
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql 5.7 support the JSON data types and a few functions related.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT(sizescolors, '$.size')) = 'M'
```